# How to make a div fit 100% of an enclosing div - even when there is padding

Tags: css

I am filling the width of my page with four square divs, separated by 10px gutters. The square divs scale inside responsively with the width of the page.

Within each block, I am trying to put a div which I wish to make fill its container (I will be loading an image into it, which I want to be square, but I want it the right size in css to avoid Content Layout Shift).

See the code below. It doesn't work, which you can see by the fact that the divs come out cyan, not magenta, because the `height:100%` directive takes 100% of the height of the enclosing block, which is zero. What I need is 100% of the height of the enclosing block **including padding**.

I've tried adding `box-sizing:border-box;`, to no avail.
Any ideas on how to achieve this in pure CSS (i.e. no Javascript)?

```
<style>
.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:10px;
  width:100%;
}
.block{
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:100%;
  background-color:cyan;
}
.inner{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:magenta;
}
</style>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='block'><div class='inner'>One</div></div>
<div class='block'><div class='inner'>Two</div></div>
<div class='block'><div class='inner'>Three</div></div>
<div class='block'><div class='inner'>Four</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the .block relative and the .inner absolute. This will remove .inner from the flow and ignore the parent elements (.block) height

```
.block {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: magenta;
  position: absolute;
}
```